# Как сделать так, чтобы команда /start исполнялась независимо от register_next_step_handler Telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Обычный хендлер на команду /start не работает когда бот запускает другой хендлер.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
```

У меня все прописано через `bot.register_next_step_handler()` и получается что когда бот запускает другой хендлер, то верхний хендлер на `/start` не действует.
Можно ли сделать чтобы когда бы пользователь ни ввел `/start`, исполнялся основной хендлер старта?

Comment: Рекомендую перейти на aiogram там есть стейты, которые можно использовать значительно удобнее. Ибо register_next_step_handler буквально делает так чтобы сработал исключительно тот хендлер/функция которую вы указали в нем

Answer (score 1):

next_step_handler и создан для того чтобы перекрывать другие хендлеры в нужный момент. Так что только в коде шаманить. Например сделать проверку во всех функциях которые вызываются через next_step_handler

```py
if message.text == r'\start'
    start_funk(message)
    return
```